How can I tell if commercial packaging is suitable for Sous Vide cooking?
Looking at the Serious Eats website, J. Kenji López-Alt cooks a gammon (ham) joint sous vide in the original packaging.
As vacuum sealed produce in the UK doesn't have any certification mark as to the type of plastic (Unlike food containers etc.), how can I tell if I can safely repeat this process with other products e.g. Steaks, Corn etc?
https://www.seriouseats.com/sous-vide-city-ham-with-balsamic-brown-sugar-glaze-recipe

That recipe isn't actually cooking the ham, just warming it up, so you really can't extrapolate from that to other recipes.

Honestly, you can’t.
Food packaging like that is not certified to be safe for cooking. Even if it happens to be safe for cooking, the manufacturer isn’t going to say so. They haven’t done the leg work to verify that it is, and don’t want to be responsible if they get it wrong. Lopez-Alt is playing it a little loose with safety there. He’s probably not wrong about it being food safe, but he has no way of knowing for certain.

That is why I spend a small fortune on sous vide vacuum bags.
